# Flash memory read access in microcontrolers

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, flash-memory

I use rh850 microcontroler and compiler green hills. The access to flash memory in this controler is for one assembly instruction ld.b. The write access take more instructions and time(access to specific address few times).

Are there microcontroler with not direct read access to to flash?

Comment: Why you want a uC with no direct flash memory access? Microchip microcontrollers take a concrete sequence to read from flash memory if I don't recall it wrong, but I don't see why anyone would like to slow down the read process.

Comment: Well this for personal curiousity, I was wondering is there a case (microcontroler) where read access is more complicate.

Comment: Anything that used NAND flash memory would require reading an entire page in order to read any byte of the page. NOR flash memory doesn't have that problem though. I'd assume you'd only see NAND flash as external flash memory, either in a separate chip or in something like an SD card. In the later case reading the flash is definitely more complicated than a single instruction.

Comment: Well, then yes, there are multiple access types to flash (we're talking about embedded flash, right?), some are seen as external hardware and need a bank change and/or register configuration, others need an unlock sequence and so on, each microcontroller is a different world.

Comment: I was asking about internal flash. Could you explain how is realizing read access to internal NAND flash in details or give a link. Even disassembler for specific controller and compiler.

Comment: You question is too broad. You can google for "NAND Flash datasheet" or "NOR Flash datasheet" to get some popular Flash ROM datasheet. There you'll find the pinout and the commands to read/write the ROM. Once you know how to drive the physical pins you can check a specific uC to see how those pins are wired. Driving them from software could be as easy as performing a memory access, a bus access or as complicated as passing through several bridges that connect busses of different nature. We can't just explain every possible arrangement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk about MCUs which runs code from own flash memory, obviously that access to this memory should be as fast as possible.
Therefore, read access to data in same flash "automatically" became fast and quick.

There is one characteristic in MCUs with [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture). Because RAM and flash connected to different buses, it mapped to different address spaces. This MCUs (most common example - Atmel AVR) uses separate commands to read data from flash and RAM.